# Three way server table check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three linked servers they replicate.  Then every two hours. I would like to double check on a highly transactional table to make sure that it is in sync. So server A = server B and server B = Server C. So I have a script that currently fails now and again due the time it takes (select count from..A,B,C do they match). Due to statement being few milliseconds a drift as it is run sequentially and end up with +/- rows are when the total is calculated. My question is there a method to query tables on three server all at the same time, or a snapshot in time option or any other best practice for acutely checking three tables on three servers all at the same time. (Table has circa 4 Million rows on SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a column that stores the date/time that records are added then you can use this to get an accurate count at a point in time across the database.

So firstly set up a variable to hold the `datetime` checkpoint:

```
declare @dateTimeCutOff datetime = GETDATE()
```

I'm not sure how you're running the checks as you've not provided any code, but you would use this value to query the databases across the servers:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM TransactionTable
WHERE DateAdded <= @dateTimeCutOff
```

If you run this query against the 3 database tables with the same variable value (which is only set up once and shared between the checks), they should produce the same result.

Comment: Do your `SELECT` `WITH (LOCK)` it will help not locking the table while selecting

Answer (score 0):

If you are only checking the `count` of the tables on the 3 servers I might create a `PROCEDURE` on the servers that will execute the `COUNT` on the linked server like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spc_GetTableCount @TableName sysname AS
DECLARE @RowVal int,
        @SQLString nvarchar(max)
SET @SQLString = N'Select @RN=COUNT(*) from ' + @TableName + ' WITH (NOLOCK)'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@RN int OUTPUT', @RN = @RowVal OUTPUT
RETURN ISNULL(@RowVal, 0)
```

Then you can execute this from any linked server

```
DECLARE @RN int
exec @RN = servername.dbname.dbo.spc_GetTableCount 'TABLENAME'
Select @RN
```

The `WITH (NOLOCK)` will make sure that you don't lock the table while selecting